# Cannot install openvino using android chaquo plugin

Tags: python, android, openvino, chaquopy

I am using Chaquo plugin to run some python code in my android app
I followed the instructions as below, but when I try to install openvino package I got the following error:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement openvino==2023.1.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for openvino==2023.1.0

I tried too many openvino versions, and different python versions put It keeps showing the error in build process.

I tried to install the same package on my mac laptop and it is installed fine.

Here is my build project details:

plugins block in project level file:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.1" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.0" apply false
    id("com.chaquo.python") version "14.0.2" apply false
}
```

plugins block in module level

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("com.chaquo.python")
}
```

defaule config block

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "my app id"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"
        }

        python {
            version "3.8"
            pip{
                options "--extra-index-url", "https://pypi.org/project"
                install "openvino"
            }
        }
    }
```

I did not write any code yet, the project build keeps fail due to the mentioned error

Comment: `openvino` doesn't appear in the list of supported packages: https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/tree/master/server/pypi/packages Should you wish to port it, see: https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/tree/master/server/pypi#chaquopy-packages

Comment: Unfortunately this package isn't available for Android yet. For updates, please subscribe to [this issue](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/969).

Answer (score 0):

OpenVINO™ Toolkit and PyPI package is only supported for the following Operating Systems:

- Ubuntu* 22.04 long-term support (LTS), 64 bit (Kernel 5.15+)
- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, 64 bit (Kernel 5.15+)
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with limitations, 64 bit (Kernel 5.4+)
- Windows® 10 and 11
- macOS* 10.15 and later, 64 bit
- Red Hat* Enterprise Linux* 8, 64 bit

Refer [System Requirements](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/openvino-toolkit/system-requirements.html) for more information.